# Use of map2 or seq functions in R to fill integers between two variables

Tags: r, sh

I have a data.frame with ~200K entries that looks like this:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8)
y <- c(2, 5, 6, 8, 12)
my.list <- list(start = x, end = y) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Base on this, I want to define a new variable that will take all the integers between x and y. So, from the example above, we would have 3,4,5 for row 2 and 8,9,10,11,12 for row 5.

I approached the issue by using:

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my.list %>% mutate(new = map2(start, end, `:`))
```

---

but given that it retrieves a list I don't know how to save it later as a data frame.

Any clue how to solve it? Could the seq() function in R be of any use in this context? Since it's such a huge data frame, would it be easier to solve with some command in the shell?

Any hint is more than welcome.

Comment: Nice job getting a workable example. Can you add information on what you want the final output to look like? Do you want the sequence in a column but not as a list? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `rowwise`

```
my.list %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = map2(start, end, `:`))
```

or

```r
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8)
y <- c(2, 5, 6, 8, 12)

library(tidyverse)

my.list <- list(start = x, end = y) %>% as.data.frame()

my.list %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = map2(start, end, seq)) %>% 
  unnest(c(new))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    start   end   new
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     2     1
#>  2     1     2     2
#>  3     3     5     3
#>  4     3     5     4
#>  5     3     5     5
#>  6     5     6     5
#>  7     5     6     6
#>  8     6     8     6
#>  9     6     8     7
#> 10     6     8     8
#> 11     8    12     8
#> 12     8    12     9
#> 13     8    12    10
#> 14     8    12    11
#> 15     8    12    12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yuriy. That unnest saved my day :) Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but using a for loop should work.

```
for(row in length(x) {
    my.list <- rbind(my.list(c(x[row]:y[row]))
}
```

The syntax may not be exactly right but, the concept should work as a starting point. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenient way to do it in `base`

```
my.list$list_col <- mapply(`:`, my.list$start, my.list$end)
```

And if you want to do it in `dplyr` try

```
my.list <- 
  my.list %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(list_col = list(start:end))
```